# Bare minimum Transformer (Keras)

Tags: keras, transformer

I'm experimenting with Transformers for a time-series prediction problem, where inputs are $k$-length sequences and outputs are scalar values.

Looking at the [Keras Transformer example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/), my question is - what components of the example are actually required? Reproducing the Keras example below:

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res

def build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0,
    mlp_dropout=0,
):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Looking at the code, what is the purpose of `LayerNormalization`?

[Edit] For anyone stumbling on this question, the version on Keras' [tutorial page](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_transformer/) is different to if you google "keras transformer tutorial". The example above was based on the google result. You will notice that LayerNormalization is before multi-head attention which doesn't make much sense to me.[\Edit]

Comment: did you succeed? would like to know what you found out

Comment: @intStdu I found that the version of the example on Keras' page if you click through from the tutorial link is different to what you get when you google. Here is the link: https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_transformer/

Comment: It's slightly different to the above, you'd notice that the ordering of the layers is different. It's multi-head attention first then dropout and layer normalisation, which makes more sense to me. The above is layer normalisation first which doesn't make much sense.